# Nodemailer: socket hang up and port is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to send an email from a internal server in my company. This server only allows internal emails. Problem is, when I try to send email using Nodemailer I allways get ESOCKET error. I've checked with the server responsible and host and port options are ok, so it should work. On this server, no authentication is required, that's why I don't have those configurations on transporter object.
Bellow is my code:

Also did some test sending email from gmail, outside the internal network, and worked fine. So Nodemailer usage seems ok.

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.internalserver.com',
    port: 25,
    secure: false,
    //requireTLS: false
});

let mailOptions = {
    from: 'email@internalserver.com',
    to: 'team@internalmail.com',
    subject: 'Alert',
    text: 'msg'
};
return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

I tried to change the host to the IP address and, in this case, I get socket hang up error and I see that the port (previously set to 25) becomes undefined. What is very strange is that, If a set the port to more than 2 digits it (obviouly doesn't wor) but it doesn't become undefined:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: '10.100.10.10',
        port: 25,
        secure: false,
        //requireTLS: false
    });
```

Bellow is the error when using the 1st transporter option with "smtp.internalserver.com":

```
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND smtp.internalserver.com
    at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
  code: 'EDNS',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'smtp.internalserver.com',
  command: 'CONN' }
```

The error using the second option with the IP address:

```
Error: socket hang up
    at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1135:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: config.email_config.SMTP_HOST,
    port: config.email_config.SMTP_PORT, // use default  port 587
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    auth: {
        user: config.email_config.SMTP_AUTH_USER,
        pass: config.email_config.SMTP_AUTH_PASS
    }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work either. Authentication is not requeired on this server. As for the port, it has to be 25, I've tried with 587 before and it didn't work because it's an internal server and the responsible said it has to be port 25.